# Deployment is selecting its pods using selector which match the label.. can it match different pod specs?

Tags: kubernetes

Deployment is selecting its pods using selector which match the label.. can it match different pod specs?
For example can you match a few pods with different specs? or all pods must be the same?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your query, are you asking whether a deployment should contain pods of the same specification.


In general all the pods in a deployment have the same specifications and you can create pods with different specifications in a namespace.

Comment: can you select pods with different specification by giving the different pods same label and use the same selector in the deployment?

Comment: The term `Deployment` in kubernetes is used when you are trying to manage a set or group of Identical resources, It's like a template using which we can create pods belonging to a particular specification and functions similar to managed instance groups in various cloud providers. The conclusion is in a deployment you can only have pods with the same spec you can't have pods with varying specs.